# jquery find and replace dynamic element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, replace

I am currently using this plugin http://roy-jin.appspot.com/jsp/textareaCounter.jsp at http://writer.knowconceptdesign.com/ with the hopes of creating an open source right tool. Everything is working fine except that when the Char limit is 0 or less the string replace of the plugin is set to not return. What I would like to do is return "None" or "No Limit set" if the char limit is 0 or less.

Here is the plugin code for showing the limit.

```
function formatDisplayInfo(){
        var format = options.displayFormat;
        //When maxCharacters <= 0, #max, #left cannot be substituted.
        if(maxCharacters > 0){
            format = format.replace('#left', numLeft);
        }
        return format;
```

I am trying to overwrite this on my main page

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
var count_options = {
    'maxCharacterSize': 0, // Just some default value
    'originalStyle': 'originalDisplayInfo',
    'warningStyle': 'warningDisplayInfo',
    'warningNumber': 40,
    'displayFormat': '#input Characters | #left Characters Left | #words Words'
};

// Initialise the plugin on document ready
$('#textinput').textareaCount(count_options);

$('#max_char').keyup(function () {
    var max_char = +$(this).val();

    //if the input is not a valid number
    if ((isNaN($('#max_char').val())) || ($('#max_char').val() == 0)){
    max_char = -1;
    var char_left = count_options.displayFormat;
    char_left = char_left.replace('#left', 'No Limit');
    count_options.displayFormat = char_left;
    }
    count_options.maxCharacterSize = max_char;



    // Unbind the 3 events the plugin uses before initializing it
    $('#textinput')
        .next('.charleft').remove().end()
        .unbind('keyup').unbind('mouseover').unbind('paste')
        .textareaCount(count_options);

});
```

This is the block I thought would fix the problem:

```
    if ((isNaN($('#max_char').val())) || ($('#max_char').val() == 0)){
max_char = -1;
var char_left = count_options.displayFormat;
char_left = char_left.replace('#left', 'No Limit');
count_options.displayFormat = char_left;
```

It seems to not be overwritten no matter what I do. I think even a simple find and replace would work. I've even tried a few find and replace plugins.

Any help would be great.

Here is the HTML for anyone who may wanta see it:

```
<textarea cols="68" rows="21" name="textinput" id="textinput"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="textbox" id="max_char" name="max_char" value="0" /> Max Characters <br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resovled with the following code:

```
$('#max_char').keyup(function () {
var max_char = +$(this).val();
var char_left = count_options.displayFormat;
if (isNaN(max_char) || max_char <= 0){
        max_char= -1;
        char_left = char_left.replace('#left', 'No Limit');
        char_left = char_left.replace('Characters Left', '');

}
else{
          char_left = char_left.replace('No Limit','#left Characters Left' );

}
count_options.maxCharacterSize = max_char;
count_options.displayFormat = char_left
```

**UPDATE** This seems to be simpler and not require replace

```
  if (isNaN(max_char) || max_char <= 0){
            max_char= -1;
            char_left='';
            char_left='#input Characters | #words Words';  

    }
    else{
            char_left='';
            char_left='#input of #max Characters | #left Characters Left | #words Words';  


    }
```

Comment: I have to ask: What is this `char_left='';` doing?

Comment: @polarblau I don't know, I'm really new to javascript. I thought I needed to "reset" the count to null before setting the value. If that's not the case I'll remove those lines and see what happens.

Comment: No need to `reset` a variable. When you assign a new value (which basically also what you do by assigning an empty string) the old value will be overridden. You can leave these lines simply away.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I've understood you correctly (am I'm not sure that I have), I'd guess that you can solve this with a callback — something like this:

```
var options = {
    'maxCharacterSize': 0,
    'originalStyle': 'originalDisplayInfo',
    'warningStyle': 'warningDisplayInfo',
    'warningNumber': 40
};

var format = function(data) {
    var left = data.left + " Characters Left",
        maxChar = $('#max_char').val();
    if (isNaN(maxChar) || maxChar <= 0) left = "No Limit";
    return data.input + " Characters | " + left + " | " + data.words + " Words";
};

$('#textinput').textareaCount(options, format);
```

Comment: I can't quite seem to get that to hook into my function.